# Exporting HTML/CSS with Inkspace or Gimp

Tags: html, css, gimp, inkscape

Is it possible to design web pages using Inkspace or Gimp and export them as HTML/CSS?

- I want a solution where I design using drag/drop and don't have to write lots of HTML/CSS bu hand all the time
- I prefer using open source software
- For Gimp I found [this](http://registry.gimp.org/taxonomy/term/383), but not sure if this really works
- For Inkspace I found tutorial [here](http://tucson-labs.com/creating-websites-with-inkscape/), but this doesn't seem to export HTML/CSS from it

Please share your experiences/ideas

Thank you

Comment: You can try something free and open-source - http://microweber.com

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to design web pages
>   using inkspace or gimp and export them
>   as html/css?

No

> I want a solution where I design using
>   drag/drop and don't have to write lots
>   of HTML/CSS bu hand all the time

For the past 20 years or so, we've seen dozens and dozens of products come and go all trying to do that. None of them really work.

---

I'd suggest one of these options:

- learn the medium (HTML, CSS, JS). That's your best bet.
- take time to set up (or hire someone) a proper CMS for you. [WordPress](http://wordpress.com/) is one of the popular open source options. Once it's set up, you can update your site without having to touch HTML/CSS
- Work with someone that can take your visual designs and turn them into HTML/CSS/JS for you. This is still not an ideal workflow, but would give them the 'drag and drop' freedom you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Learn to code, its the only way, there are so many WYSIWYG editors on the market that really dont do as good a job as the knowledge contained in a 4 inch thick HTML & CSS bible.

You want to build websites, learn to code.

When I was at Uni we had a lecturer that made us code JavaScript using Notepad, nightmare at the time but it taught us the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the plugin you mentioned, I have just been using it it will export a layout in css but you still have to update and fill in the tags with your content etc. so a little learning of CSS is required. If you need it to export images as well I would suggest using the http://registry.gimp.org/node/18440 and then http://registry.gimp.org/node/20778 to optimis
e+ the image sizes.

Ian

Answer (score 0):

GIMP and Inkspace are both image editors, the latter being an SVG image. While you could make a webpage that has images, you'd generally not want to use just an image, as that cannot have links, selectable text, etc.

If it must be a WYSIWYG editor, try OpenOffice.org and export to HTML.

Comment: I'd guess that word browsers are going to add a bunch of junk to the HTML (at least regarding my experiences with Microsoft Word; never used OpenOffice before).

Comment: Loads. Personally, I'd recommend learning HTML and CSS, but if it's just a one time site or nothing big, they can manage, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

While not an HTML editor, there is an option in GIMP to slice an image, and export it as an HTML table, with onmouseover effects for basica animation. You have to have GIMP-Python installed (authomatic on Linux, but requires some steps on Windows) -- then check for the filters->web->pyslice.    It can save some time in design for menu areas and such.

To create the whole page, however, you have to edit HTML by hand.