# Turning a GIMP layout into a web page

Tags: html, css, gimp

What are the beginner basic steps to turn a GIMP layout into a real web page?

It seems looking at the following article that gimp is not the right tool for making CSS.  Use a CSS/HTML editor instead.  [Exporting HTML/CSS with Inkspace or Gimp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463462/exporting-html-css-with-inkspace-or-gimp)   That said, I already have a web page layout in GIMP that I want it to become a real web page.

What is the easiest way to turn this into a real web page?  What would I do with each layer and how can I make my web page look exactly like my gimp layout?

Comment: You should learn how to write CSS and HTML by hand. It will serve you better in the long run.

Comment: By hand. Start slicing up the layout and writing HTML. There is no good tool for doing this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, ou would want to make the entirely outside of GIMP. You might be able to get GIMP to export the site, but the result wouldn't be anywhere near what you would get if you coded it from the ground up.

You would then use GIMP to slice the design into the image assets you need for your website and include them with CSS or inline, depending on what the element was.

Answer (score 0):

What I would say is the best way to convert a GIMP (or Photoshop, etc.) document into a web page is to write HTML and CSS to mimic the image you created. HTML and CSS are both simple to learn, plus [there](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/12-converting-a-photoshop-mockup-part-two-episode-one/) [are](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/13-converting-a-photoshop-mockup-part-two-episode-two/) [various](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/14-converting-a-photoshop-mockup-part-two-episode-three/) [tutorials](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/72-building-a-website-2-of-3-htmlcss-conversion/) [online](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/58-html-css-the-very-basics/).

WYSIWYG editors, even GIMP or Photoshop can generate very poor unstable, dirty HTML source.